# Using Splunk rex command to extract a field between 2 words

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

Please assist extracting\creating a new field between 2 fixed words, one of which begins with `!`

Example:

```
!CASH OUT          $50.00!                        !TOTAL AUD    $61.80!
```

`!CASH OUT` and `!TOTAL` are fixed but the value amount in between (`$22.00!`) changes. I would like to create a field so I can filter the events by the cash out amount ect. I would only want the dollar amount to be the field without the `!` at the end.

I've tried the below search but it creates a cashout field with all data after `!CASH OUT`  and doesn't cut the field before `!TOTAL`

```
"CASH OUT" "!TOTAL" | rex "CASH OUT (?.*)!TOTAL"

search | "CASH OUT" "!TOTAL" | rex "CASH OUT (?.*)!TOTAL"
```

`field = $50.00`

Answer (score 1):

`rex "(?<total>\$[^!]+)"`

Into capturing group called total, capture anything that begins with a dollar sign, followed by everything that isn't available exclamation mark.

`rex "\$(?<total>\[^!]+)"`

If you don't want to include the dollar sign in the captured field